# Query Rails models using URL_PARAMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making Rails app and in my model I have Application model. Application model belongs to User, and it has user_id as an attribute in Application model.
The route for getting all Applications is like below:

```
GET    /applications(.:format)      Controller#Action applications#index
```

When I issue get request to above route, I get back all Applications. Let's say there are two models:

```
Application 1:
{
user_id:1,
data:{}
}

Application 2:
{
user_id:2,
data:{}
}
```

I would want to just query Application2 using user_id: 2. I issues GET request using url_params like following way but it did not work.

```
localhost:3000/applications?user_id=2
```

Is this not the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually helps a lot to post more of your actual code. If you post your models and existing index method code, I might be able to give you a more accurate response, but this should probably work based off my assumptions.

Find applications filtering based on the user_id using a where clause

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @applications = Application.where(user_id: params[:user_id])
    # Render your json response using whatever method you want. Jbuilder, rabl, to_json, etc
  end
end
```

Hope that helps, feel free to add more info and I'll edit